# Mac OS Bootcam Windows 7 install stuck

Tags: windows-7, mac, boot-camp, bsod

I am trying to install Windows 7 via Bootcamp. Now the installation yields a bluescreen with nvlddmkm.sys error.
I want to restart the installation again, but I am stuck to get the CD out - even booting with pressed option key does not allow me to boot via my Mac Partition.
What is the best way to get the Windows DVD out and try to work with a fresh Snow leopard DVD?
Edit:I actually managed to get the Win DVD out, but now I can not manage to start with the Snow Leopard DVD.

Comment: Also, for future reference, by holding down the left mouse button during boot you can force a Mac to eject the disk.

Good luck with the reinstall! :)

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to use an HP keyboard instead of the Mac keyboad - I could then press the alt key and was back in business to reinstall.

Comment: You answered your own question. Mark it so.